# How to implement an API call linked to a Provider using SOLID principles in a Flutter app?

Tags: json, flutter, solid-principles, flutter-provider

I am trying to refactor my Flutter weather application.

It eventually calls an API to provide weather data based with a location as a parameter.

Currently, I have :

- A WeatherJSONModel.dart which corresponds to the JSON response given by the API I use.
- A WeatherAPI.dart files which manages to call the API with the parameters, and parse the JSON response into a the above model.
- A WeatherModel.dart which is the model for the data displayed by the app.
- A WeatherProvider (extends ChangeNotifier) which converts the WeatherJSONModel returned by the API into a WeatherModel then made available for the app.

I very much doubt this the most efficient way to do it, but can't find how to properly implement my calls.

Should it be more APICallClass into ResponseHandlerClass into ProviderClass ?

Thank you !

TLDR; How to implement API calls and JSON parsing following SOLID principles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best tutorials on this topic in flutter (in my opinion) can be found here:

https://github.com/ResoCoder/flutter-tdd-clean-architecture-course

There is also a [written series](https://resocoder.com/flutter-clean-architecture-tdd/) and a 7 hour [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjE2IDphA_U&list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4iYGE_khpXRdJkJEp9WOech) of this:

Here is the architectur proposal:

[image]